# RandomizedSearchCV does not work in a Pipeline when evaluating alternative classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In Scikit Learn, RandomizedSearchCV can work for evaluating different parameters in a pipeline, but only in some cases where the classifiers share similar/same parameters.  When you pass blocks of parameters for different classifiers it fails when GridSearchCV succeeds.

You will notice in the code below, the problem setup is the same for gridsearch and random search but only random search fails.

```
numpy.random.seed(52)
MY_RAND_SEED=numpy.random.seed(52)


pipe = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler' , StandardScaler()),
    ('classify', LogisticRegression())
])

X, y = make_classification(n_samples= 500, n_features=58, n_redundant=13, n_informative=7, n_clusters_per_class=2)

param_grid_linear = [
    {'classify' : [LogisticRegression(),],
     'classify__penalty' : ['l1', 'l2'],
     'classify__C' : numpy.logspace(-4, 4, 50),
     'classify__solver' : ['liblinear']},
    {'classify' : [LogisticRegression(),],
     'classify__penalty' : ['l2'],
     'classify__C' : numpy.logspace(-4, 4, 50),
     'classify__solver' : ['lbfgs']},
    {'classify': [SVC(),],
     'classify__kernel': ['linear',],
     'classify__C': numpy.linspace(0.001,200, 10),},
]


innercv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=numpy.random.seed(52))
gridA = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid_linear, scoring='accuracy', iid=False, verbose=1, n_jobs=12)
gridA.fit(X, y)
print("finished grid search")

gridB = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe, param_grid_linear, scoring='accuracy', n_iter=5, iid=False, verbose=1, n_jobs=12)
gridB.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: btw, it fails with an attribute error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: With some further investigation I see that square brackets are a problem for RandomizedSearchCV but not GridSearchCV.  I don't know if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, usually one passes only lists of dictionaries as parameters {dict, dict, dict}, but to do what I suggested above requires passing a list of lists of dictionaries, which is currently only accepted by GridSearchCV.
RandomizedSearchCV does not accept this now but will in a future release of sklearn.  Here is a response I received on GitHub:

From: Thomas J Fan 
Date: Wednesday, August 14, 2019 at 7:13 PM

This was addressed in #14549
This feature is not released yet, but you can try it out by installing the nightly build of scikit-learn:
pip install --pre -f https://sklearn-nightly.scdn8.secure.raxcdn.com scikit-learn